# Consumer thread waiting on multiple qeueues

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have multiple queues of tasks and a `consumer` thread.

`Consumer` thread should wake up once any of the queues has a task. So I wonder what is the best way to make such kind of communication.

These are some implementations which can solve this and explanation why I want to find something different:

- One way to implement that is to use some monitor object and call
  `.wait(timeout)` on it from a consumer thread and call `.notify()`
  from producer threads. However this approach uses `wait/notify` which
  is kind of low-level api, so I to avoid using it if possible. Also it's not always correct, in some cases we can end up waiting for the whole timeout, while we have tasks to do (sleeping barber problem).
- Something like `CountDownLatch` with `reset` method would do well,
  but I didn't find anything like that in `java.util.concurrent`. Implementation would be fairly simple, however implementing new bicycle is something I want to avoid even more then `wait/notify`. Also I believe it has the same problem with waiting for the whole timeout as the `wait/notify` approach.
- Make producer wrap created entities into some `Task` and make all producer write to the same queue, so that consumer would listen to a single queue. This approach is actually very good in most cases I believe, but in my case this part of application has low-latency requirements, so I must avoid creating new objects(e.g. these wrappers) and also it would increase contention on the tail of the queue(instead of one consumer, all of them would write there) which is not very good for latency too.

So are there any other ways to implement it?(may be using some other concurrency primitives)

Comment: Sounds like a BlockingQueue would work. When a produce has a task, it adds it to the BlockingQueue, and the consumer would start working until the queue is empty and it waits again.

Comment: Are these queues blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: @matt but the problem is that there are multiple queues, how I can wait on all of them at same time. Imagine a case when I am waiting on one queue, and then there is a task in another queue which also need to execute.

Comment: Why add to several queues in the first place? Add to a single blocking one, and have a single master consumer distributing the work as it arrives. If you do have several queues, have a consumer for each that just puts items into the matter queue.

Comment: @NengLiu any implimentation would do, however it shouldn't have limited capacity(in decent terms of course, I understand that the heap isn't infinite)

Comment: @daniu I explained why I don't want to use such approach in my question.

Comment: Your discussion of why you don't want to use a single queue is mis-informed. I would look at MPSC lock free queues - for example [here](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues).

Comment: @BoristheSpider great suggestion, I just wanted to find something without using thirdparty libraries, however if I wouldn't find a better solution will probably use something like this.

Comment: Since it's essentially a performance issue, I have to ask if you measured the different solutions. I don't really believe the single queue multiplexing adds enough latency to offset the gain in speed, simplicity and maintainability.

Comment: @daniu problem is not so much in latency of the single queue, but the thing that I will need to create wrappers for this objects, allocating garbage, which will lead to longer gc pauses. whole module is written in gc free manner because of that. And yes there are very specific low latency requirements.

Comment: For low latency you shouldn't really be blocking/waiting/sleeping at all - as [1024 cores](http://www.1024cores.net/) points out. What you want is a non-blocking queue - such as [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) then poll the queues in a tight loop - if power consumption is a concern, add backoff. If you can stand 15ms pauses from locking, then this isn't low latency.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I didn’t say I use blocking queues actually. You are completely right. However we have limited number of cores and this thread is expected to sleep when there is now work to be done, and that is completely fine, as in one application there can be different part with different latency requirements, problem is that consumers are more sensitive to latency, though they are not blocking. Producer can wait if there are no tasks to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using task notification queue, in this scenario if any of task queue adds and item it also add item to ntification queue.

The following snipped illustrates this approach:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class Main<T1, T2>  {


  Queue<T1> taskType1Queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<T1>(10);
  Queue<T2> taskType2Queue= new ArrayBlockingQueue<T2>(10);
  ArrayBlockingQueue<Boolean> notificationQueue= new ArrayBlockingQueue<Boolean>(2);


  public void produceType1(T1 task) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        taskType1Queue.add(task);
        notificationQueue.offer(true);; //does not block if full
      }
    });
  }

  public void produceType2(T2 task) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        taskType2Queue.add(task);
        notificationQueue.offer(true); //does not block if full
      }
    });
  }


  public void consume() {

    try {
      notificationQueue.take();//wait till task1 o task2 has been published

      for(;!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();){
        T1 task1 = taskType1Queue.poll();//does not block if queue is empty
        if (task1 != null) {
          //do something
        }
        T2 task2 = taskType2Queue.poll();//does not block if queue is empty
        if (task2 != null) {
          //do something
        }
        if(task1 == null && task2 == null) {
          break;
        }
      }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Consumer thread done");
      return;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: @RuslanAkhundov The notification queue doesn't block if full, so your task queue can fill up (up to 10 tasks) but the notification will only post wake up twice. Also, you have gone from using 1 queue, that would not block when things are posted to and be available to consume all the time a consumer is ready, to using three queues, which could not easily be extended if you want another producer.

Comment: @matt first of all I can use unbounded queue for task queues instead of bounded. You are right regarding that it would be hard to add another consumers, but it's not possible for me to use 1 queue for all tasks now. I can write to this queues from different consumers which are producing same kind of tasks, in other words I have a queue per task type, which in my case, I believe, works perfectly well.

Comment: @RuslanAkhundov As you haven't shown the tasks, there is no way to say. The answer provided here is broken, maybe you have made it work, so that's good for you.

Comment: @matt notification queue blocks unless it has some item (docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/… take: Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available) , the idea is that if there is at least one item in any queues, notification should not block but let the individual queue to be examined without being blocked (see null checks for non empty item in worker queues), please elaborate what is broken

Comment: @AdrianWitas the problem is your offer, if you offer multiple tasks before your other tasks have finished your notification queue will be shorter than your task queue. Hence you'll have tasks that are not getting completed while you're blocking on take.

Comment: @matt, I good point, updated the snippet to address this concern.

Comment: You've pretty much turned a BlockingQueue into a wait notify.

Comment: @matt, correct that is the function of notification queue in this simple approach, it blocks till at least one items are added to any of worker queues, a notable notification queue of size 1 would do too. One can explore to use ReentrantLock, or Semaphore as alternative approaches,  but initial execution order needs to be examined much closely.